# Check for one-element list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm very new to Prolog (coming from C++) and am having trouble understanding using lists as parameters. In particular, I am wondering how to account for the case in which a list only has one element (the tail is "empty"). Why can't I have [L] as a parameter by itself? Why must a tail be explicitly included?

```
/** Trying to print out the head of the list */
writeList([L|_]) :- write(L).      /** Works fine */
writeList([L]) :- write(L).        /** Doesn't work. Will return false, but why? */
writeList([L]) :- write([L]).      /** I thought I'd try this to see if it was a 
                                   problem with write(), but this returns false as well. */
```

The only way solution I came up with (without creating tests after the ":-") was:

```
writeList([L|[]]) :- write(L).
```

But it seems a bit messy to have to specify the tail is [].  Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Sorry if this question is very silly--I've tried to find an answer to this (quite basic) question but I suspect there's a problem in my fundamental understanding here.

Comment: The predicate `writeList([L]) :- write(L).` worked fine for me. My goal was `?- writeList([alice]).`.

Comment: Do keep in mind that prolog goals either succeed or fail, they don't __return__ true or false.

Comment: I think I was calling it wrong (I looked back and I kept doing writeList(alice) and somehow kept forgetting the brackets each time).  Looks like my confusion was just from a very silly error--thank you for the answer, that's what made me realize.

Answer (score 8):

The notation `[X|Y]` refers to a list whose first element is `X` and whose tail is `Y`.

The underscore `_` is an anonymous variable and means *any term*. That's not what you want in this case.

A one-element list have an empty tail, so `Y` is bound to an empty list `[]`, then the notation is: `[X|[]]`

In a similar way, for a two-element list: `[X,Y|[]]`

Check [this Prolog Lists tutorial](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse13) for more on this topic.

Comment: Good answer! Just a small addition: Simply write `[X]` for a one-element list, and `[X,Y]` for a two-element list.

Comment: @mat That's cleaner!. Im really used to the [] thing. Thanks.

Comment: @mat Quite late comment but for `[X]` - if I use `[_]` instead, it seems like it just cover all possible length. In that case `[_|[]]` is only option like the answer I assume?